# QGraphicsView visualization becomes very slow while panning or zooming if rotated text is added to Scene

Tags: python, pyqt5, qgraphicsview

I have a data set that makes a network (`m_ramales` pickle file), this is drawn in a `QGraphicsView` which has interaction properties such as movables nodes and selections options. This GUI need to handle in the order of 3000 nodes, every edge needs to show a description data text as the example shows.

There are two problems:

1. Panning and zooming becomes very slow while rotated text is shown in the `QGraphicsView` scene.
2. If in `QGraphicsView` class `setViewport` is set to `QtOpenGL.QGLWidget()`, problem number 1 is fixed but the quality of the drawn decades greatly and it has  isual errors while moving nodes from original position.

I need to obtain a `QGraphicsView` that has an acceptable drawing quality, and that has acceptable performance while the user is panning or zooming. Is this possible?

The example code is below, please copy the pickle file in the same folder as the example script.

Data for example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k0wZ5Logfu7pfyDJmJyF0VZvOne94H7Y/view?usp=sharing

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtOpenGL
import pickle


def rotate_vector(origin, point, angle):
    """
    Rotate a point counterclockwise by a given angle around a given origin.

    The angle should be given in radians.
    """
    ox, oy = origin
    px, py = point

    qx = ox + np.cos(angle) * (px - ox) - np.sin(angle) * (py - oy)
    qy = oy + np.sin(angle) * (px - ox) + np.cos(angle) * (py - oy)
    return qx, qy

def ang_vector(x_v, y_v):
    y_v, x_v = np.asarray(y_v), np.asarray(x_v)
    return (np.degrees(np.arctan(np.true_divide(y_v[1:] - y_v[:-1], x_v[1:] - x_v[:-1]))), list(zip(np.sign(x_v[1:] - x_v[:-1]), np.sign(y_v[1:] - y_v[:-1]))))


dict_pos = {(1, 1): [-1, 1], (-1, 1): [-1, 1], (-1, -1): [-1, -1], (1, -1): [-1, -1]}
font_family = 'Arial Unicode MS'
dat_Font = QtGui.QFont("Arial", 1.9, QtGui.QFont.Normal)


class GraphicsView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, scene, parent):
        super(GraphicsView, self).__init__(scene, parent)
        "VARIABLES INICIALES"
        self.pos_init_class = None
        "ASIGNAR LINEAS DE MARCO"
        self.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        "ACTIVAR TRACKING DE POSICION DE MOUSE"
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        "REMOVER BARRAS DE SCROLL"
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        "ASIGNAR ANCLA PARA HACER ZOOM SOBRE EL MISMO PUNTO"
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        "MEJORAR EL RENDER DE VECTORES"
        self.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.setOptimizationFlags(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.DontAdjustForAntialiasing or QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.DontClipPainteror or QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.DontSavePainterState or QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.DontAdjustForAntialiasing)
        self.setCacheMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.CacheBackground)
        # self.setViewport(QtOpenGL.QGLWidget())


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        pos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
        "Pan mouse cursor"
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.MiddleButton:
            self.pos_init_class = pos
            QtWidgets.QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QtCore.Qt.ClosedHandCursor)
        super(GraphicsView, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        "Pan"
        if self.pos_init_class:
            delta = self.pos_init_class - self.mapToScene(event.pos())
            r = self.mapToScene(self.viewport().rect()).boundingRect()
            self.setSceneRect(r.translated(delta))
        else:
            super(GraphicsView, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        "Pan"
        self.pos_init_class = None
        QtWidgets.QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor)
        super(GraphicsView, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        "ZOOM"
        scale_factor = 1.25
        if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
            self.scale(scale_factor, scale_factor)
        else:
            self.scale(1 / scale_factor, 1 / scale_factor)

class Node(QtWidgets.QGraphicsEllipseItem):
    r_pozo = 0.45
    def __init__(self, arrow, hydraulic_text, ang, point,rect=QtCore.QRectF(-r_pozo, -r_pozo, 2 * r_pozo, 2 * r_pozo), parent=None):
        super(Node, self).__init__(rect, parent)
        "arrow"
        self.arrow = arrow
        "hydraulic text"
        self.hydraulic_text = hydraulic_text
        "angle"
        self._angle = ang
        "point"
        self.origin = (np.array([0, 0, 0]), np.array([0, 0, 0]))
        self.point = point
        "edges"
        self.edges = []
        self.setZValue(1)
        self.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.darkGray)
        self.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(51, 153, 255), 0.1))
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)

    def addEdge(self, edge):
        self.edges.append(edge)

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemSelectedChange:
            self.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.green if value else QtCore.Qt.darkGray)
        if change == QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionHasChanged:
            for edge in self.edges:
                "angulo de linea antes de ajustar"
                x1, y1 = edge.dest.x(), -edge.dest.y()
                x2, y2 = edge.source.x(), -edge.source.y()
                ang1 = np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1))
                "diferencia de angulo actual con anterior"
                ang = ang1 - self._angle[edge.toolTip()]
                "actualizar angulo anterior"
                self._angle[edge.toolTip()] = ang1

                "Ajustar linea"
                edge.adjust()

                "Arrow position"
                x_arrow = (edge.source.x() + edge.dest.x()) / 2.0
                y_arrow = (edge.source.y() + edge.dest.y()) / 2.0
                self.arrow[edge.toolTip()].setPos(x_arrow, y_arrow)
                "Arrow rotation"
                x_rot, y_rot = rotate_vector(self.origin, self.point[edge.toolTip()], np.deg2rad(-ang))
                self.arrow[edge.toolTip()].elementPath.setElementPositionAt(0, -x_rot[0], -y_rot[0])
                self.arrow[edge.toolTip()].elementPath.setElementPositionAt(1, -x_rot[1], -y_rot[1])
                self.arrow[edge.toolTip()].elementPath.setElementPositionAt(2, -x_rot[2], -y_rot[2])
                "actualizar nueva posicion de PathItem"
                self.point[edge.toolTip()] = (x_rot, y_rot)

                "Hydraulic_text position"
                angle_array, cuad_array = ang_vector(x_v=[edge.source.x(), edge.dest.x()],
                                                     y_v=[edge.source.y(), edge.dest.y()])
                text_width = self.hydraulic_text[edge.toolTip()].boundingRect().width() * 0.5
                dx, dy = text_width * np.cos(np.radians(abs(ang1))), text_width * np.sin(np.radians(abs(ang1)))
                pos0, pos1 = dict_pos[cuad_array[0]]
                dx, dy = dx * pos0, dy * pos1
                "Hydraulic_text rotation"
                if 90 < -ang1 < 180 or -90 > -ang1 > -180:
                    self.hydraulic_text[edge.toolTip()].setPos(x_arrow - dx, y_arrow - dy)
                    self.hydraulic_text[edge.toolTip()].setRotation(180 - ang1)
                else:
                    self.hydraulic_text[edge.toolTip()].setPos(x_arrow + dx, y_arrow + dy)
                    self.hydraulic_text[edge.toolTip()].setRotation(-ang1)

        return super(Node, self).itemChange(change, value)

class Edge(QtWidgets.QGraphicsLineItem):
    def __init__(self, source, dest, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QGraphicsLineItem.__init__(self, parent)
        self.source = source
        self.dest = dest
        self.source.addEdge(self)
        self.dest.addEdge(self)
        self.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red, 0.2))
        self.adjust()

    def adjust(self):
        self.prepareGeometryChange()
        self.setLine(QtCore.QLineF(self.dest.pos(), self.source.pos()))

class GripItem_Arrow(QtWidgets.QGraphicsPathItem):
    def __init__(self, angle):
        super(GripItem_Arrow, self).__init__()
        origin = (np.array([0, 0, 0]), np.array([0, 0, 0]))
        point = (np.array([0.6, -0.6, -0.60]), np.array([0, 0.4, -0.4]))
        self.x_init, self.y_init = rotate_vector(origin, point, np.deg2rad(-angle))

        arrow = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        arrow.moveTo(self.x_init[0], self.y_init[0])
        arrow.lineTo(self.x_init[1], self.y_init[1])
        arrow.lineTo(self.x_init[2], self.y_init[2])

        self._arrow = arrow
        self.setPath(self._arrow)

        self.setBrush(QtGui.QColor("green"))
        self.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor("green"), 0.))
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        self.setZValue(2)
        self.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))

    @property
    def elementPath(self):
        return self._arrow

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionChange:
            self.setPath(self._arrow)
        return QtWidgets.QGraphicsPathItem.itemChange(self, change, value)


class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    "TAMAÑOS ELEMENTOS"
    def __init__(self):
        "TAMAÑO MAINWINDOW"
        self.main_width, self.main_height = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(0).width(), QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().height()

    "PLOT FUNCTIONS"
    def plt_plot(self):
        "LOAD DATA"
        pkl_file = open('m_ramales.pkl', 'rb')
        m_ramales = pickle.load(pkl_file)
        pkl_file.close()
        ramal = m_ramales.keys()

        "CREAR DICCIONARIOS"
        dict_node = {}
        dict_arrow = {}
        dict_edge = {}
        dict_angle = {}
        dict_point = {}
        dict_hydraulic_text = {}
        origin = (np.array([0, 0, 0]), np.array([0, 0, 0]))
        point = (np.array([0.6, -0.6, -0.60]), np.array([0, 0.4, -0.4]))

        for j in ramal:
            x = m_ramales[j]['X']
            y = m_ramales[j]['Y']
            angle_array, cuad_array = ang_vector(x_v=x, y_v=y)

            for i in range(0, len(x) - 1, 1):
                if i == 0:
                    "coords"
                    x1, y1 = x[i], -y[i]
                    x2, y2 = x[i + 1], -y[i + 1]
                    "nombre Tramo"
                    str1 = m_ramales[j]['Tramo'][i+1]
                    "angulo"
                    dict_angle[str1] = np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1))
                    "puntos iniciales"
                    dict_point[str1] = rotate_vector(origin, point, np.deg2rad(-dict_angle[str1]))
                    "flecha"
                    dict_arrow[str1] = GripItem_Arrow(angle=-dict_angle[str1])
                    "asignar posicion de flecha"
                    dict_arrow[str1].setPos((x1 + x2) / 2.0, (y1 + y2) / 2.0)
                    "asignar identificador de flecha"
                    dict_arrow[str1].setToolTip(str1)
                    "agregar a escena"
                    self.graphicsView.scene().addItem(dict_arrow[str1])


                    "agregar texto"
                    dict_hydraulic_text[str1] = QtWidgets.QGraphicsSimpleTextItem()
                    "definir tipo de texto, fuente y tamaño"
                    dict_hydraulic_text[str1].setFont(dat_Font)
                    "agregar contenido del texto"
                    text_dat = str1 + '\n' + 'D = 300 mm PVC'
                    dict_hydraulic_text[str1].setText(text_dat)
                    "ajustar posicion del texto"
                    text_width = dict_hydraulic_text[str1].boundingRect().width() * 0.5
                    dx, dy = text_width * np.cos(np.radians(abs(dict_angle[str1]))), text_width * np.sin(
                        np.radians(abs(dict_angle[str1])))
                    pos0, pos1 = dict_pos[cuad_array[i]][0], dict_pos[cuad_array[i]][1]
                    dx, dy = dx * pos0, dy * pos1
                    x_m, y_m = (x1 + x2) / 2.0, (y1 + y2) / 2.0
                    "asignar posicion y rotacion del texto"
                    dict_hydraulic_text[str1].setPos(x_m + dx, y_m + dy)
                    dict_hydraulic_text[str1].setRotation(dict_angle[str1])
                    "asignar nombre de tramo"
                    dict_hydraulic_text[str1].setToolTip(str1)
                    "agregar a escena"
                    self.graphicsView.scene().addItem(dict_hydraulic_text[str1])


                    "nombres de nodos"
                    node_str1 = 'Node.' + m_ramales[j]['Ramal'][0] + '.' + m_ramales[j]['Pozo'][i]
                    node_str2 = 'Node.' + m_ramales[j]['Ramal'][0] + '.' + m_ramales[j]['Pozo'][i + 1]
                    "crear nodos"
                    dict_node[node_str1] = Node(arrow=dict_arrow, hydraulic_text=dict_hydraulic_text, ang=dict_angle, point=dict_point)
                    dict_node[node_str2] = Node(arrow=dict_arrow, hydraulic_text=dict_hydraulic_text, ang=dict_angle, point=dict_point)
                    "asignar posicion de nodo"
                    dict_node[node_str1].setPos(x1, y1)
                    dict_node[node_str2].setPos(x2, y2)
                    "agregar nodo a escena"
                    self.graphicsView.scene().addItem(dict_node[node_str1])
                    self.graphicsView.scene().addItem(dict_node[node_str2])
                    "crear linea"
                    dict_edge[str1] = Edge(dict_node[node_str1], dict_node[node_str2])
                    "asignar nombre de tramo"
                    dict_edge[str1].setToolTip(str1)
                    "agregar a escena"
                    self.graphicsView.scene().addItem(dict_edge[str1])

                else:
                    "coords"
                    x1, y1 = x[i], -y[i]
                    x2, y2 = x[i + 1], -y[i + 1]
                    "nombre Tramo"
                    str1 = m_ramales[j]['Tramo'][i+1]
                    "angulo"
                    dict_angle[str1] = np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1))
                    "puntos iniciales"
                    dict_point[str1] = rotate_vector(origin, point, np.deg2rad(-dict_angle[str1]))
                    "flecha"
                    dict_arrow[str1] = GripItem_Arrow(angle=-dict_angle[str1])
                    "asignar posicion de flecha"
                    dict_arrow[str1].setPos((x1 + x2) / 2.0, (y1 + y2) / 2.0)
                    "asignar identificador de flecha"
                    dict_arrow[str1].setToolTip(str1)
                    "agregar a escena"
                    self.graphicsView.scene().addItem(dict_arrow[str1])


                    "agregar texto"
                    dict_hydraulic_text[str1] = QtWidgets.QGraphicsSimpleTextItem()
                    "definir tipo de texto, fuente y tamaño"
                    dict_hydraulic_text[str1].setFont(dat_Font)
                    "agregar contenido del texto"
                    text_dat = str1 + '\n' + 'D = 300 mm PVC'
                    dict_hydraulic_text[str1].setText(text_dat)
                    "ajustar posicion del texto"
                    text_width = dict_hydraulic_text[str1].boundingRect().width() * 0.5
                    dx, dy = text_width * np.cos(np.radians(abs(dict_angle[str1]))), text_width * np.sin(np.radians(abs(dict_angle[str1])))
                    pos0, pos1 = dict_pos[cuad_array[i]][0], dict_pos[cuad_array[i]][1]
                    dx, dy = dx * pos0, dy * pos1
                    x_m, y_m = (x1 + x2) / 2.0, (y1 + y2) / 2.0
                    "asignar posicion y rotacion del texto"
                    dict_hydraulic_text[str1].setPos(x_m + dx, y_m + dy)
                    dict_hydraulic_text[str1].setRotation(dict_angle[str1])
                    "asignar nombre de tramo"
                    dict_hydraulic_text[str1].setToolTip(str1)
                    "agregar a escena"
                    self.graphicsView.scene().addItem(dict_hydraulic_text[str1])
                    dict_hydraulic_text[str1].setCacheMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.NoCache)


                    "nombres de nodos"
                    node_str1 = 'Node.' + m_ramales[j]['Ramal'][0] + '.' + m_ramales[j]['Pozo'][i]
                    node_str2 = 'Node.' + m_ramales[j]['Ramal'][0] + '.' + m_ramales[j]['Pozo'][i + 1]
                    "crear nodos"
                    dict_node[node_str2] = Node(arrow=dict_arrow, hydraulic_text=dict_hydraulic_text, ang=dict_angle, point=dict_point)
                    "asignar posicion de nodo"
                    dict_node[node_str2].setPos(x2, y2)
                    "agregar nodo a escena"
                    self.graphicsView.scene().addItem(dict_node[node_str2])
                    "crear linea"
                    dict_edge[str1] = Edge(dict_node[node_str1], dict_node[node_str2])
                    "asignar nombre de tramo"
                    dict_edge[str1].setToolTip(str1)
                    "agregar a escena"
                    self.graphicsView.scene().addItem(dict_edge[str1])


    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        "DEFINIRI WIDGET DE MAIN WINDOW"
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        MainWindow.setWindowState(QtCore.Qt.WindowMaximized)
        "SIZE MAIN WINDOW"
        MainWindow.resize(self.main_width, self.main_height)

        "DEFINIR GRAPHIC WIDGET"
        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.graphicsView = GraphicsView(scene=self.scene, parent=self.centralwidget)
        "POSICION Y TAMAÑO DE GRAPHIC WIDGET"
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, self.main_width, self.main_height))
        "DIBUJAR PLOT"
        self.plt_plot()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    QtWidgets.QApplication.setFont(QtGui.QFont(font_family, 10, QtGui.QFont.Normal))
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is not resolved, having said that there is a workaround to it by changing the Cache Mode on text items of the shown area.

It is possible to obtain an acceptable pan and zoom performance event with thousands of Text items in the scene by selecting text items on the observable area of the scene and changing their Cache mode from:

`setCacheMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.DeviceCoordinateCache)`

to:

`setCacheMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemCoordinateCache)`.

This is done after the wheel event is over and triggered by a QtCore.QTimer()
 signal set around 150 ms.

If it is of any help, this is a snippet of code used. However, any help on improving this would be appreciate as I am fairly new to PyQt5.

```py
    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        "Change Cache Mode"
        self.update_text = self.items(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, self.viewport().width(), self.viewport().height()))
        scene_extent = self.mapToScene(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, self.viewport().width(), self.viewport().height())).boundingRect()
        self.x_orig, self.y_orig, self.scene_width, self.scene_heigth = scene_extent.x(), scene_extent.y(), scene_extent.width(), scene_extent.height()
        if self.scene_width > self.len_scene:
            [i.setCacheMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemCoordinateCache) for i in self.update_text if i.type() == 9]

        "ZOOM"
        scale_factor = 1.25
        if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
            self.scale(scale_factor, scale_factor)
        else:
            self.scale(1 / scale_factor, 1 / scale_factor)

        "set emit signal QTimer"
        self.t.timeout.connect(self.suspend_text)
        self.t.start(150)
```

```py
  def suspend_text(self):
        "Select text on the current scene area"
        self.update_text = self.items(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, self.viewport().width(), self.viewport().height()))
        "self.len_scene is the width of the scene neccesary to begin to see text and needs to be clear(No Cache)"
        if self.scene_width < self.len_scene:
            "type 9 is the type of the Text item"
            [i.setCacheMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.DeviceCoordinateCache) for i in self.update_text if i.type() == 9]

        "Stop Timer signal"
        self.t.stop()
```